# execute/render a directive from another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following 2 directives. In `DirectiveA` I am getting some data from remote server and then rendering a template with that data as `anchor` tag. Now when user click on any of the link, I `broadcast` event and listen to that event in `DirectiveB`. In DirectiveB I want to make another ajax request and when I receive response with data then I want to render `DirectiveB` template. My current approach does not work because it executes both of the Directives in the beginning and at that time I do not have any data for `DirectiveB`. Below is the code

DirectiveA

```
angular.module('app').directive('DirectiveA', function ($http) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/templateA.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.showDetails = function (num) { // <-- this executes in ng-click in template
                $scope.$broadcast('season', num);
            };
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            $http.get(attributes.resource).then(function (response) {
                scope.rows = response.data;
                scope.seasons = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < scope.rows.length; i++) {
                    var num = parseInt(scope.rows[i].data);

                    if (year >= 2005 && year <= 2015) {
                        scope.seasons.push({ 'data': scope.rows[i].data });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is DirectiveB

```
angular.module('app').directive('DirectiveB', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/templateB.html',
        controller: function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.$on('season', function ($scope, num) { // I listen to that event
                $http.get('http://demo.com/api/' + num).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.standings = response.data;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here is how I am using it in HTML

```
<directive-a resource="http://demo.com/api/>
</directive-a>

<directive-b></directive-b>
```

**UPDATE**

**I am still waiting for its solution.**

**UPDATE 3**

templateA

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="row in seasons"> 
        <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails(row.season)">{{ row.season }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Template B

```
<h3>Standings</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="standing in standings" ng-if="state">{{ position  }}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in standings">
            {{ row.Driver  }}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show the hierarchy of those 2 directives? I assume directiveA is parent of the directiveB as you use broadcast.

Also can you give an example of the html template?

Comment: @DB.Null please check my update in my question.

Comment: I am still waiting for help.

Comment: Anyone who can help me solve this issue? I am still waiting for its solution.

Comment: @2619- In case this is yet to be resolved, is it possible for you to setup a plunker/fiddle and share it?

Comment: Do you need it to be two directives? have you looked into using different routes?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to listen to a certain event inside a `directive`. Did you think about adding 2nd `directory` template dynamically from a `Controller`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question boils down to:

1. How to ensure the communication between `DirectiveA` and `DirectiveB`

   As both your directives use the same scope, your solution with event broadcasting works. This would break once you change the `scope` setting inside [DDO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) to anything else but `false`.

   That's why I'd advise you `$broadcast` the event on `$rootScope`.
2. How to render `DirectiveB`'s template once data is ready

   A simple `ngIf` wrapping the directive's template would do the job. We don't need anything fancy for this.

Bellow is a simple working example. Notice how both directives use an isolated scope - this is just to showcase why you need `$rootScope.$broadcast`. I'm also using `$timeout` in order to simulate the server's latency.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .directive('directiveA', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'tempA.html',
      controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.sendMessage = function(message) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', message);
        };
      },
      scope: {}
    };
  })
  .directive('directiveB', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'tempB.html',
      controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.messages = [];

        $rootScope.$on('eventName', function(event, message) {
          $timeout(function() {
            $scope.messages.push(message);
          }, 50);
        });
      },
      scope: {}
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <directive-a></directive-a>
  <directive-b></directive-b>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tempA.html">
    <h2>Hello from DirectiveA</h2>
    <label>
      <p>Message to send to DirectiveB</p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="toSend">
    </label>
    <button type="button" ng-click="sendMessage(toSend); toSend = '';">Send</button>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tempB.html">
    <div ng-if="messages.length > 0">
      <h3>Hello from DirectiveB</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">{{ message }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an API (angular service) to communicate between your directives. In my Example i call it MyAPIService :

```
angular.module('app').service('MyAPIService', function () {
   this.display = false;
   this.seasons = [];
});
```

Then inject instance of your API in both directives and inside your directive A, you have to fill your seasons and update your "display" variable when you click on your anchor. On your directiveB, just watch "display" variable

```
angular.module('app').directive('DirectiveA', function ($http, MyAPIService) {
'use strict';

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/templates/templateA.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.showDetails = function () { 
           MyAPIService.display = true;
    },

    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        $http.get(attributes.resource).then(function (response) {
            scope.rows = response.data;
            MyAPIService.seasons = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < scope.rows.length; i++) {
                var num = parseInt(scope.rows[i].data);

                if (year >= 2005 && year <= 2015) {
                    MyAPIService.seasons.push({ 'data': scope.rows[i].data });
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
angular.module('app').directive('DirectiveB', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: 'templates/templateB.html',
       controller: function($scope, $http, MyAPIService) {
           // WATCH "DISPLAY" VARIABLE AND CALL YOUR AJAX
       }
   };
});
```

Comment: Here when I check for `MyAPIService.display` then still it does not work. Because the controller is already executed when application is loaded in the beginning. That means the if condition in directiveB controller is also executed to false because at that time display property is set to false.

Comment: @2619 This is the best solution so far. Better would be using *require*. The $scope/$rootScope event to share data is *very bad*.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working solution for you, a little different than your broadcasting approach. As you mentioned, you want to load Data for Directive B only after the click of Directive A. So, We will be putting one condition to remove Directive B from the DOM. And When the click of Directive A triggers at that point we will be making the Directive B load in DOM. That Way Your Directive B's Controller will be loaded at a later point of time.

Here is the code to support my argument

Directive A

```
angular.module('app').directive('DirectiveA', function ($http) {
'use strict';
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/templates/templateA.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.showDetails = function (num) { // <-- this executes in ng-click in template
            $scope.isDirectiveBVisible = true;
        };
    },

    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        $http.get(attributes.resource).then(function (response) {
            scope.rows = response.data;
            scope.seasons = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < scope.rows.length; i++) {
                var num = parseInt(scope.rows[i].data);

                if (year >= 2005 && year <= 2015) {
                    scope.seasons.push({ 'data': scope.rows[i].data });
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Directive B

```
angular.module('app').directive('DirectiveB', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/templateB.html',
    controller: function($scope, $http) {

            $http.get('http://demo.com/api/' + num).then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
            });

    }
};
});
```

HTML

```
<directive-a resource="http://demo.com/api/>
</directive-a>

<directive-b ng-if="isDirectiveBVisible"></directive-b>
```

Comment: Just to clear. The ng-click for list item will be inside directive-a i.e. inside TemplateA.html

Answer (score 1):

> Long time ago I've created [this solution](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngDirective) like experiment
>
> ```
> <div ng-directive="{{directive}}"></div>
> ```
>
> in which  you can dynamically render directives.

But you question is not about dynamic rendering. **It's about changing state of component(directive)**.

You was already provide with answer about using `ngIf`, the thing is only in place where to put it. I would suggest to put it inside your directive and make wrapper for the whole template:

```
<div ng-if="isShown">
  <h3>Standings</h3>
  ...
</div>
```

And set `isShown` scope property in place where you need it, for example after event:

```
 $scope.$on('season', function ($scope, num) { 
    $scope.isShown = true;   
 });
```

or after ajax call:

```
$http.get('http://demo.com/api/' + num).then(function (response) {
    $scope.isShown = true;
});
```

Also I would suggest to play not only with visibility but with **loading indication** to show that it's loading:

```
<div ng-if="isShown">
   <loading-indicator ng-if="isLoading">
   <div ng-if="!isLoading">
     <h3>Standings</h3>
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an ng-if and some kind of flag in Directive A to indicate that the ajax request is complete. ng-if wraps the hidden element in comments so they are absent from the dom until the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

From ["AngularJs $scope documentation"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

> Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

This means your directiveB has to be child of your directiveA in order to catch the broadcast event. For example:

```
<directive-A>
    <directive-B></directive-B>
</directive-A>
```

Directive's controller's function code will execute prior to html render and link's function code post html render. This means you cannot handle the execution of directiveB . You can simple create it when you have the response from the call you made in directiveA. For example:

```
scope.data={resolved:false};
$http.get(attributes.resource).then(function (response) {
                scope.rows = response.data;
                scope.seasons = [];
                scope.data.resolved = true;

                for (var i = 0; i < scope.rows.length; i++) {
                    var num = parseInt(scope.rows[i].data);

                    if (year >= 2005 && year <= 2015) {
                        scope.seasons.push({ 'data': scope.rows[i].data });
                    }
                }
            });
```

And in the above example of HTML:

```
<directive-A>
    <directive-B ng-if="data.resolved"></directive-B>
</directive-A>
```

With this way your directiveB will be created when your call is resolved.

**ATTENTION** though: If you use the ngIf you might lose the $broadcast event since your directiveB's $on will be created after the $broadcast

Comment: on a side note, if i were you i would stick the ngClick functionality inside the directiveB because it seems to me that it belongs there, you click a number and gets the data. Using $broadcast here looks like an overkill

Comment: Well what I want is to render DirectiveB template when on click in triggered in DirectiveA.  I already tried that approach but the problem is the ajax request is asynchronous. which means that in order to make resolved se to true, as you suggested, then template should keep listening to DirectiveB controller in order change the state of resolved. So it won't and does not work.

Comment: I am sorry the resolved variable should be placed in the $http.get of the directiveA. Check edited Answer

Comment: @db-null thats still not gona work. As I need to have data in DirectiveB.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution, **if you want to keep the two directives**, is to use `ng-if` directive in your Diretive B template to show the table only when there are results in it.

You only have to modify your Directive B template to add a condition to your current table, and also add a `<div>` or similar to show a message when the user hasn't selected any item yet.

Your Directive B template would be something like:

```
<h3>Standings</h3>
<!-- Add ng-if here -->
<table ng-if="standings.length > 0">
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="standing in standings" ng-if="state">{{ position  }}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in standings">
            {{ row.Driver  }}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- and also here -->
<!-- If standings is not an array -->
<div ng-if="!standings.length">
    <p>Please, select one of the items above to show standings.</p>
</div>
```

You can add as many divs with conditions as you may need. For example, you may add a message for when there are no results for the selected item:

```
<!-- If standings is an array but it is empty -->
<div ng-if="standings.length && standings.length > 0">
    <p>There are no standings to show.</p>
</div>
```